# Formatear un string a un arreglo de float64 con fmt.Sscanf de Golang

Tags: go

Tengo lo siguiente:

```golang
str1 = string(p)  //contiene 7 valores con retornos

var float64Array [7]float64

fmt.Sscanf(str1, "%g\n%g\n%g\n%g\n%g\n%g\n%g", &float64Array[0], &float64Array[1], &float64Array[2], &float64Array[3], &float64Array[4], &float64Array[5], &float64Array[6])
```

Lo anterior sí funciona, pero no recuerdo en qué lenguaje se puede hacer una especie de loop para evitar repetir `%g\n` y `&float64Array[0], .. &float64Array[6]`: si mal no recuerdo es en fortran.

La pregunta concreta es si en go se puede hacer algo parecido.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.